# Game "Zen Bound 2" from Humble Bundle doesn't run

Tags: 12.04, games

I bought the latest humble indie bundle and installed the 64-bit deb of Zen Bound 2 on my Ubuntu 12.04 Intel-based desktop system using Ubuntu Software Centre by clicking the deb. Nothing happens when I run the game from the Dash, and when I run it from the terminal I get this:-

`alan@wopr:~$ zenbound2`

```
Setting Video Head to 0
Setting Resolution 1920, 1080
```

Any ideas what to try next?

Comment: It is doing the same in my 12.04 64bit Desktop, must be a software issue. Maybe report it to the humblebundle guys?

Comment: Ok, I have used the bug reporting form on their site to send them details of the problem. Will report back when I get a response.

Comment: If its a software issue flag this. If it can be solved within Ubuntu add an answer and you will get some rep up (at least from me ;)). Thanks for taking the time to report it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit the file ~/.ZenBound2/zb2config.ini and switch the antialias value to false.

All thanks to José Neto comment: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/03/latest-humble-bundle-brings-4-new-games-to-linux/#comment-472599409